# Remove <img> tag containing a word from Html string using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm a total newbie with `preg_replace`...

Basically I have a long html string and I'd like to remove from it all img tags that have `Tracker.php` in their SRC

ex : `<img src='http://website/Tracker.php?var1=5&var2=8'>`

And I have tried `$ct=preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $string);` to remove `<img>` tag from string and it's not working properly.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @GiamPy So far i found : $ct=preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $string);
But this will remove all img tags in the String not just the ones with tracker.php in their src... Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php
$var = "abc<img src='http://website/Tracker.php?var1=5&var2=8'>def";
echo 'Before replace: <textarea style="width:800px;">' . $var . '</textarea><br/>';
$var = preg_replace('~<img[^>]{1,}Tracker.php[^>]{1,}>~', '', $var);
echo 'After replace: <textarea style="width:800px;">' . $var . '</textarea><br/>';
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How to do it in Laravel blade?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post after a good reply. I was testing my solution in the meanwhile and this works fine too. I add the case insensitive options and short quantifier.

Have a nice day!

```
$str = preg_replace( '/<img[^>]*Tracker[^>]*>/i', '', $var );
```